# SQL query that requires multiple select queries in one

Tags: sql, database

I study database in college now and in my project I have 3 tables: `League`, `Team` and `Has`

- League (leagueId, leagueName)
- Team   (teamId, teamName)
- Has    (leagueId, teamId, year)

I need to make a list of all the teams that play in 2 or more leagues (Team_Name and League_Name) [in one year]

Eg.

```
  League                    Team                          Has
  leagueid | leaguename     teamid | teamname       leagueid | teamid | year
  1        |  SerieA           1   | Juventus          1     |   1    | 2016
  2        | ChampionsL.       2   | Man.Utd           2     |   1    | 2016
  3        |  PremierL.        3   | Arsenal           3     |   2    | 2016
                                                       2     |   3    | 2013
                                                       2     |   3    | 2014
```

The result should be :

```
Team_Name  |  League_Name
 Juventus  |  SerieA
 Juventus  |  ChampionsL
```

I wrote this code but obviously it's incorrect, so I don't know how to continue

```
select
    t.teamname,
    l.leaguename
from
    team t,
    league l,
    has h
where
    t.teamid   = h.teamid and
    h.leagueid = l.leagueid 
group by
    t.teamname,
    l.leaguename
having
    count( l.leagueid ) >= 2
```

Note: My professor insists that we use DBeaver and I use Windows 10, so not everything works well.

Comment: I suggest you use explicit `JOIN` syntax instead of the "multiple-FROM" syntax.

Comment: BTW, do your tables have foreign-key constraints defined?

Comment: [Hint](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php)

Comment: Yes, but I didn't wrote them because I thought it was necessary. I have 7 other tables but for this question I only need this data from this tables.
I tried with join but it also wasn't working because when I write group by t.teamname, l.leaguename the result is wrong.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out. It worked for me.

```
CREATE TABLE League ( leagueId INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, leagueName VARCHAR(20)); 
GO

CREATE TABLE Team ( TeamId INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, TeamName VARCHAR(20))
 GO
CREATE TABLE Has ( TeamId INT FOREIGN KEY (TeamId) REFERENCES Team(TeamId), 
                    leagueId INT FOREIGN KEY(leagueId) REFERENCES League(leagueId)) 


SELECT tn.TeamName, lg.leagueName
FROM Team tn
JOIN Has ha ON tn.TeamId = ha.TeamId
JOIN League lg ON ha.leagueId = lg.leagueId 
WHERE tn.TeamId IN (
                    SELECT  h.TeamId
                    FROM Team t
                    JOIN Has h ON t.TeamId = h.TeamId
                    JOIN League l ON h.leagueId = l.leagueId 
                    GROUP BY h.TeamId
                    HAVING COUNT(h.leagueId) > 2)
```

Comment: @Nela If it works Please don't forget to accept it as the answer. Good luck with your class

Comment: Yeah it works and it's in my project. Thank you very, very much.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
SELECT t.teamname, l.leaguename
FROM Team t
JOIN Has h ON t.teamid = h.teamid
JOIN League l ON h.leagueid = l.leagueid 
WHERE t.teamid IN (                  
    SELECT teamid
    FROM Has
    GROUP BY year, teamid
    HAVING count(teamid) >= 2)
```